Redirect to external site using PHP and send access token and retrieve it in Struts Application
I am trying to redirect to external site and i need to pass access token in headers or as form , here is what i am trying to do
Html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Submit POST Request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/some_action" method="POST" name="Form">
        <label for="x-access-token">X-Access-Token:</label>
        <input type="text" id="xAccessTokenId" name="xAccessToken" value="How">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

and in Struts 1
public ActionForward login(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String actionResponse = ActionForwardConstants.SUCCESS;
        ActionErrors errorsMessages = new ActionErrors();
        
        MyForm yourForm = (MyForm) form;

But i am not able to get in form ( access token)
